# Found Seq[(String, play.api.libs.json.JsValue)] required scala.collection.Map[String,play.api.libs.json.JsValue]

Tags: scala, play-json

Upgrading from play-json_2.11 2.3.x to play-json_2.12 2.6.0, throws a bunch of errors. One of them is Found Seq[(String, play.api.libs.json.JsValue)]  required scala.collection.Map[String,play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
Here's the code snippet: This was resolved by converting to map

```scala
def process(text1: String, text2: String): String = {
  var seq:Seq[(String, JsValue)] = Seq.empty[(String, JsValue)] 
  //some processing on seq 
  return new JsObject(seq).toString()
}
```

What should be the return changed to return a map instead of a seq? Also is there a migration guide that can be used to successfully migrate to play-json_2.12 2.6.0

Edited question: + symbol no more supported in play json 2.6

code snippet:

```
var jsonObject1: JsObject = new JsObject(seq.empty.toMap)
jsonObject1 = jsonObject1 + ("key","value")
```

Getting an error: cannot resolve + symbol in above code, which was supported in play json 2.3

Comment: Try `seq.toMap`.

Comment: And do not use `var`

Comment: Nor `return` :)

Comment: Thanks @jwvh also the + symbol is not resolved anymore with play json 2.6
How do we add a key value pair to a JsObject as shown in the edited code above?